# when @user is blank, how to make this if statement work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a header partial linked to my application.html.erb that looks like this:

```
<header class="unselectable">
  <h2 class="float_left">
    <% if @user.try(:errors).present? %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= @title %>
    <% end %>
  </h2>

  <nav class="round">
    <ul>
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Home", current_user %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Log out", logout_path %></li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

This is all well and good unless the page that loads doesn't have an @user variable (such as an about or logout page) in which case i get this:

```
undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I make this work?  I tried changing the logic to render the title `unless` `@user.errors.any?`but that didn't work either.  I'm sure this is a simple fix but I can't figure it out!

**EDIT** added the fixes suggested (updated in the header partial above) and now get this error:

`No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}` which seems to be coming from the `edit_user_path`

Comment: try this: `edit_user_path(current_user)` @dax

Comment: that works!  Thanks!  I think @amesee solution is a bit cleaner, but this is working fine for my uses at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the method `.try(:something)`:

```
<% if @user.try(:errors).present? %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
<% else %>
  <%= @title %>
<% end %>
```

- If `@user` is `nil`, the `.try(:errors)` will not raise an error.
- The `.present?` method works for `nil` too:

.

```
>> nil.present?
#=> false
>> false.present?
#=> false
>> [].present?
#=> false
>> ''.present?
#=> false
>> 'bonjour'.present?
#=> true
>> ['bonjour'].present?
#=> true
```

- `.present?` is a combination of `.nil?` AND `.empty?`
- `.present?` is actually the opposite result of `.blank?`

Comment: Note that `.any?` needs to be changed to `.present?` or some method that is nil-safe.

Comment: thanks!  got this, which doesn't make sense - it's routing to users#edit:
  No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}

Comment: Well can you post the content of your  app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb around line 14 please?

Comment: yeah, will try to figure it out and post it here.  thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

You can reformulate to like this:

```
<header>
  <h2 class="float_left">
    <% if @user.try(:errors).try(:any?) %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= @title %>
    <% end %>   
  </h2>
...
</header>
```

Or add `errors_any?` to model:

```
class User
  def errors_any?
    self.try(:errors).try(:any?)
  end
end
```

And to this:

```
<header>
  <h2 class="float_left">
    <% if @user.try(:errors_any?) %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= @title %>
    <% end %>   
  </h2>
...
</header>
```

Comment: `any?` is for array example: `[nil, nil].any?`

Comment: `present?` is for detect `blank` or `nil`: `"".present?` or `nil.present?`

Comment: `[nil,nil].present?` is `true`... but `[nil,nil].any?` is `false`

Comment: the second suggestion gives me the same error as @MrYoshiji's answer

Comment: I updated... `self.errors.any?` to `self.try(:errors).try(:any?)`... but I recommend the first suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I highly question the need for `@user` in your partial which is rendered in your application layout, hence its need in **every** page of your application. I argue that this is not good design at all because now you're relying on a global variable in all views of your application.

I think what you really mean to use is the [flash](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash). In which case you want something like this in `application.html.erb`.

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, value, class: key %>
<% end %>
```

This should be set in the appropriate controller action before it's view is rendered so that the error message displys according to the request that was just made.

If your error messages come from your models, then this should be part of what actually generates these error messages. Typically this is a call to either `create` or `update` actions in the controller. In which case you should have the `error_messages` partial rendered with the form when your validations do not pass and the form is rendered again with the model object.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <!-- and so on -->
<% end %>
```

This way you can be confident that the `@user` object is always available for the partial to render without any errors since we're explicitly passing the object to the partial itself, and the partial is being rendered with the correct context. Using `@users` in your partial itself is the equivalent of using a global variable, hence the **entire application** relying on that global variable to exist.

The `@user` object is now accessed with a local variable in the partial as `object` (or whatever your decide to end up naming it).

```
<% object.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
  <li>* <%= message %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: right i agree with you about the design choice - it doesn't really make sense.  what i want is to put either the page name OR an error message in the header - but putting `flash` in app.html.erb doesn't let me position it in the same way

Comment: I don't think mixing the logic for the page title with the logic for error messages is a good idea at all. These two are not related in any way. But please take my words only as attempts at constructive criticism. At the end of the day I really don't understand the specifics of your application so I'm just providing feedback based on "common cases."

Comment: Come to think of it, how about keep the two logic (error messages and title) separate and display one or the other with css. I think this is more appropriate in that it gives more separation of concerns between _what_ is displayed and _how_ it is displayed.

Comment: ah, don't get me wrong i'm taking it only as constructive criticism and thank you for your post - how would you suggest i display one or the other with css?

Comment: Add an `error` class or something like that to the tag that your title is in (which is separate from the tag your error messages are in). And the css could be something like `.title .error { display: none }`. This will also make the tag not take up any space as if it wasn't rendered at all.